# How to write co-related $lookup query for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

There are some tweet data like:

```json
    {
        "id": 1432568863334539264,
        "created_at": "2021-08-31 05:00:07",
        "text": "Most of New Orleans went dark on Sunday after Hurricane Ida took out eight transmission lines. A new natural gas po… ",
        "user_id": 807095
    },
{
        "id": 1432578972844531714,
        "created_at": "2021-08-31 05:40:17",
        "text": "RT @nytimes: Most of New Orleans went dark on Sunday after Hurricane Ida took out eight transmission lines. A new natural gas power plant,…",
        "user_id": 1414848022849245186,
        "retweet_id": 1432568863334539264,
        "retweet_user_id": 807095,
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "id": 807095,
                "indices": [
                    3,
                    11
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
{
        "id": 1432578589107625990,
        "created_at": "2021-08-31 05:38:46",
        "text": "RT @nytimes: Most of New Orleans went dark on Sunday after Hurricane Ida took out eight transmission lines. A new natural gas power plant,…",
        "user_id": 1345847262010875915,
        "retweet_id": 1432568863334539264,
        "retweet_user_id": 807095,
        "user_mentions": [
            {
                "id": 807095,
                "indices": [
                    3,
                    11
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want to use a single find or aggregate to resolve:

Find the general tweet that receives most retweets in the first hour after it is
published. Print out the tweet Id and the number of retweets it received within the
first hour.

my did not work script:

```
db.tweets_hurricane.aggregate([
    {$match: {retweet_id:{$exists:true}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, id: '$id', retweet_id: '$retweet_id', format_date: { $toDate: '$created_at'}, format_date_end: { $add: [{$toDate: '$created_at'}, 1*60*60*1000]}}},
    {$group: {_id: '$retweet_id',  count: {$sum: {$switch: {branches: [{case: {$lt: ['$format_date', db.tweets_hurricane.findOne({id: '$retweet_id'}, {format_date_end:1})]}, then: 1}], default: 0}}}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
    
])
```

Comment: Seems like we are giving code test here! `Find the general tweet ... within the first hour.` And we'll hopefully be compensated  with `10 SO` points. Kindly show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. I'll be happy to help :)

Comment: I am learning mongodb now, this question is too hard for me. Please help me. Thx!

Comment: Lemme see. Give me some times.

Comment: Thank you so much！

Comment: Maybe a bit difficult if your sample data is only one single tweet with 2 retweets.

Comment: @何子洋 where is the retweet count? Is the length of `user_mentions` or `user_mentions.indices` array is the retweet count?

Comment: the data don't hava field 'retweet_id' meas general tweet, the data hava field 'retweet_id' means retweet, for my examples, the tweet('1432568863334539264') has two retweets: "id": 1432578589107625990 and  "id": 1432578972844531714

Comment: I would say, the number of documents having `retweet_id`

Comment: `db.tweets_hurricane.aggregate([
      {$match: {retweet_id:{$exists:true}}},
    {$group: {_id: '$retweet_id',  count: {$sum: 1}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
])` The question is, how to add the condition:  in the first hour after it is published?

Comment: Oh now I see. Thanks

Comment: `db.tweets_hurricane.aggregate([
    {$match: {retweet_id:{$exists:true}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, id: '$id', retweet_id: '$retweet_id', format_date: { $toDate: '$created_at'}, format_date_end: { $add: [{$toDate: '$created_at'}, 1*60*60*1000]}}},
    {$group: {_id: '$retweet_id',  count: {$sum: {$switch: {branches: [{case: {$lt: ['$format_date', db.tweets_hurricane.findOne({id: '$retweet_id'}, {format_date_end:1})]}, then: 1}], default: 0}}}}},
    {$sort: {count: -1}}
    
])` this code don't work

Comment: Please edit your question and put such information there instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample data makes it difficult to understand the solution, but it should work:

```
db.tweets_hurricane.aggregate([
   // Join tweets and re-tweets
   { $match: { retweet_id: { $exists: false } } },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "tweets_hurricane",
            localField: "id",
            foreignField: "retweet_id",
            as: "retweets"
         }
   },
   // filter retweets created in the first hour after it is published
   {
      $set: {
         retweets: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$retweets",
               as: "tweet",
               cond: { $lt: ["$$tweet.created_at", { $add: ["$created_at", 1000 * 60 * 60] }] }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   // count number of retweets
   { $set: { retweet_count: { $size: "$retweets" } } },
   // limit to most retweeted tweet
   { $sort: { retweet_count: -1 } },
   { $limit: 1 },
   // finalize output
   {
      $project: {
         id: 1,
         retweet_count: 1
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: there any  another implementation?

Comment: Storing date values as string is a design flaw, you should **never** do that. That's the reason why I presumed proper `Date` objects.

Comment: Most likely other solutions exist. Are you not happy with my proposal?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took so long. I had to generate dummy data to for testing the query.
The query is very long but it's the most efficient one I that could come up with.

Note: I used the `$lookup` to find all the re-tweets. But the version of mongodb installed on my machine is `v4.4`. So I had to use an older syntax. Check out the docs for `$lookup` to use the concise syntax for mongodb `v => 5.0`.

### Algorithm

```
1 - Find all the general tweets
2 - For each general tweet find all it's retweets by checking if
  - general_tweet_id === retweet_id and the difference of milliseconds between 
  - the retweet and general tweet's
  - creation time is < 60*60*1000 (1 hour )

3 - Count the retweets array size in the `$project` statement as num_of_retweets
4 - Sort num_of_retweets in descending order.
5 - use `$limit` to pick the first result.
```

### Dummy Data

```js
const data = [
  { _id: "200", created_at: "2021-01-02 11:25:00" },
  { _id: "201", created_at: "2021-01-02 12:19:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "202", created_at: "2021-01-02 11:59:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "203", created_at: "2021-01-02 12:19:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "204", created_at: "2021-01-02 12:17:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "205", created_at: "2021-01-02 11:57:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "206", created_at: "2021-01-02 12:17:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "207", created_at: "2021-01-02 12:16:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "208", created_at: "2021-01-02 13:45:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "209", created_at: "2021-01-02 13:29:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "210", created_at: "2021-01-02 13:22:00", retweet_id: "200" },
  { _id: "211", created_at: "2021-01-01 05:28:00" },
  { _id: "212", created_at: "2021-01-01 05:59:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "213", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:05:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "214", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:11:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "215", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:16:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "216", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:00:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "217", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:22:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "218", created_at: "2021-01-01 07:09:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "219", created_at: "2021-01-01 07:41:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "220", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:54:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "221", created_at: "2021-01-01 07:09:00", retweet_id: "211" },
  { _id: "222", created_at: "2021-01-02 14:22:00" },
  { _id: "223", created_at: "2021-01-02 14:56:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "224", created_at: "2021-01-02 15:00:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "225", created_at: "2021-01-02 15:00:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "226", created_at: "2021-01-02 15:01:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "227", created_at: "2021-01-02 14:56:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "228", created_at: "2021-01-02 15:44:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "229", created_at: "2021-01-02 16:51:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "230", created_at: "2021-01-02 16:17:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "231", created_at: "2021-01-02 16:42:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "232", created_at: "2021-01-02 16:29:00", retweet_id: "222" },
  { _id: "233", created_at: "2021-01-01 03:40:00" },
  { _id: "234", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:22:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "235", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:31:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "236", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:24:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "237", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:33:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "238", created_at: "2021-01-01 06:06:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "239", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:56:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "240", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:53:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "241", created_at: "2021-01-01 04:52:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "242", created_at: "2021-01-01 05:25:00", retweet_id: "233" },
  { _id: "243", created_at: "2021-01-01 05:17:00", retweet_id: "233" },
]
```

### Aggregation Pipeline

Note: I put all this data into a collection called `test` that's why you see `"test"` in the `from` field of the `$lookup` statement. Change it to your own collection name.

```js
pipeline = [
  {
    $match: {
      retweet_id: { $exists: false },
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "test",
      let: { general_tweet_date: "$created_at", general_tweet_id: "$_id" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: ["$retweet_id", "$$general_tweet_id"] },
                {
                  $lte: [
                    {
                      $subtract: [
                        { $toDate: "$created_at" },
                        { $toDate: "$$general_tweet_date" },
                      ],
                    },
                    3600000,
                  ],
                },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
          },
        },
      ],
      as: "retweets",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      num_of_retweets: { $size: "$retweets" },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: { num_of_retweets: -1 },
  },
  {
    $limit: 1,
  },
];
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!